# How to calculate the executors, cores and memory based on a given input file size in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Lets say I have 5 GB Input File and I have Cluster Setup of 3 Data Nodes with each 25 cores (Total - 75 cores) and  72GB memory (Total - 216GB Memory).

1. How to calculate number of executors, number of cores and executor memory for this particular file size and memory configuration.
2. How many blocks will create in HDFS for this file?

Comment: This should help get an idea  https://blog.cloudera.com/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/

Answer (score 1):

Method for executor resource calculation:

- Allocate 1 core and 1 GB per node for yarn. So, we are left with 72 core and 213 GB memory.
- The remaining resource have ~1:2.95 core to (GB) memory ratio.
- The optimal CPU count per executor is 5.  So, to prevent underutilisation of CPU or memory resource, the executor’s optimal resource per executor will be 14.7GB(5*2.95) memory and 5 CPU.

You should keep block size as 128MB and use same as spark parameter:
`spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes=134217728`.
It will result in 40 blocks or partitions.

You can refer this article for more details. https://devendraparhate.medium.com/apache-spark-job-aws-emr-cluster-s3-yarn-and-hdfs-tuning-77514afb9ce8

Comment: "The optimal CPU count per executor is 5" - This is actually the max limit per executor. The cores should usually lie somewhere in between 1-5. More than 5 cores usually degrades performance. Having said that, the operation being performed should be such that it can actually benefit from the additional cores. For example, if the job spends more time in IO than processing, less cores should be able to provide more throughput.